# Как нарисовать граф связей (блок-схему) на javascript, какую библиотеку использовать?

Tags: javascript, графы, d3.js, визуализация, блок-схема

Есть задача по визуализации связей между объектами (блок-схемы).

Схема работы приложения: python скрипт берет данные из БД, немного их обрабатывает и тут должна вступать визуализация.

Python-библиотеки не подходят потому что как правило они дают статичную картинку, а мне нужен интерактивный интерфейс: перетаскивать элементы (вершины и связи), удалять элементы, добавлять новые и т.п. а потом уже сохранять результат, выводить на печать и т.д.

Пришел к выводу, что проще всего использовать javascript библиотеки типа vis.js, anychart, balkangraph или d3.

"Из коробки" ни одно из перечисленных решений не сработало как надо, у каждого есть свои недостатки типа: некрасивое, нет переноса строки в названиях нод/связей, нет возможности удалять\добавлять связи\ноды
Получается я или не там копаю или нужен специалист, который имеет опыт работы с подобными библиотеками и сможет сделать ее под мои нужды или есть какое-то другое решение\технология?
Буду рад услышать советы от тех, кто сталкивался с подобной задачей по построению блок-схем, графов связей и т.п.

Ниже пример того, что удалось слепить, бОльшей части требуемого функционала добиться не удалось

[image: Вот что удалось сделать на vis.js]

Готов взаимодействовать на коммерческой основе

Comment: Можете посмотреть в сторону gojs - отличная вещь, но платная.

Comment: Спасибо, видел, но что-то запредельно дорого

Comment: Я бы сделал на d3